# Google Javascript API 401 Invalid Credentials with Fusion Table

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-fusion-tables, http-status-code-401

401 Invalid response: This seems to be a reasonably common issue judging by the Google search responses, but unfortunately none of those have helped me to resolve my issue fully.

I have a web page which requires a Google based login, and then selects data from a fusion table. During the login process I check that the user has the appropriate access to the fusion table, so I know that the login has worked and that they are a valid user allowed to edit that table (shared to specific people). I also check that the token received is valid. So for each successful login I know that they have permission to access the table (it has been shared with them), and a valid token (they have signed in).

As this is a JavaScript app there is no Refresh Token, just the access token (online access). The prompt does say offline access but I think this is just a Google default thing. *I do not set the APIKey*, which resolved another 401 error that some users (not the same ones unfortunately) had (from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834017/google-api-401-invalid-credentials)). The request works fine in the Google Oauth developers console.

Most users can access it fine, but for **some** users when they run the query to select data from the fusion table they always get a 401 error when the GET request is sent (shows up as 401 (Unathorized) in the console and 401: Invalid Credentials in the error returned). I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine however and am stuck as to why it is happening and what I can do next.

It is very difficult to remote to the users machine, and I cannot install software on it such as Fiddler to view the headers, hence the console logging.

I have attached an image of the users console with a failed request. The GET request looks ***exactly*** the same on my machine (where it works fine). You can see that the Token is valid, they are logged in etc.

[image]

Here is a cut down version of the relevant code (sensitive information removed) and with extra debugging code in there like checkAuth, validateToken and handleAuthResult2:

```
var clientId = 'my_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var ftTableID = 'fusiontableidstring';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
var accessToken;  
var email;
var name;  
var params = {
    'clientid': clientId,
    'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
    'scope': scopes,
    'approvalprompt': 'force',
    'include_granted_scopes': true,
    'callback': handleAuthResult
    };
gapi.auth.signIn(params);

//debug code
function validateToken() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' + accessToken,
        data: null,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
            if (response.audience == clientId) {
                console.log('Our token is valid....');
            } else {
                console.log(response.audience + ' not equal to ' + clientId);
            }
        },  
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
            console.log('Our token is not valid....');
        },
        dataType: "jsonp" 
    });
}

function checkAuth() {
    console.log("checking authorization");
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {'client_id': clientId, 'scope': scopes, 'immediate': true},
        handleAuthResult2);
}

function handleAuthResult2(authResult) {
    if (authResult) { //result
        console.log(authResult.status);
        console.log(authResult);

        if (authResult.error) {
            reset();
            gapi.auth.authorize(
                {'client_id': clientId, 'scope': scopes, 'immediate': false},
                handleAuthResult);
        } else {
        }
    }
}
//end debug code

// Handle the results of the OAuth 2.0 flow.
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult) { //result
        if (authResult.error) {
            console.log(authResult.error);
            reset();
        } else {
            //successfully signed in, requests can be sent (will automatically contain access token)
            accessToken = authResult.access_token;
            validateToken(); //debug only
            //check who the user is
            gapi.client.load('plus','v1').then(function() {
                gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                    'userId': 'me'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    var profile = res.result;
                    email = profile.emails[0].value;
                    name = profile.displayName;
                    document.getElementById("signinconfirmation").innerHTML = "You are signed in as " + email + "(" + name + ")" ;
                 //check permissions
                    }).then(function() {
                        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2').then(function() {
                            gapi.client.drive.permissions.getIdForEmail({
                                'email': email,
                            }).then(function(resp) {
                                var userid = resp.result.id;
                                gapi.client.drive.permissions.get({
                                    'fileId': ftTableID,
                                    'permissionId': userid
                                }).then(function(resp2) {
                                    if(resp2.status == 200) {
                                    document.getElementById("signinconfirmation").innerHTML = "You are signed in as " + email + "(" + name + ") with correct permissions." ;
                                    } else {
                                    document.getElementById("signinconfirmation").innerHTML = name + " at " + email + " does not have the appropriate permissions to edit this table.";
                                    } 
                                },
                                 function(reason) { //drive permissions failed
                                document.getElementById("signinconfirmation").innerHTML = name + " at " + email + " does not have the appropriate permissions to edit this table.";
                                });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}

// build the request to SELECT data from Fusion Table.
function selectData() {
        var sqlValue = document.getElementById("searchvalue").value;
        var matchCondition = "CONTAINS";
        if (sqlValue.length == 0) {
            alert('No value entered!')
        } else {
            //escape single quotes in sqlValue
            sqlValue = sqlValue.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
            var sql = "SELECT ROWID, COUNTRY FROM " + ftTableID + " WHERE COUNTRY " + matchCondition + " '" + sqlValue + "' ORDER BY ADMINNAME";  
            query(sql, 'select-data-output');
        };
}
// Send SQL query to Fusion Tables.
function query(query, element) {
    var lowerCaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
    var path = '/fusiontables/v2/query';
    var callback = function(element) {
        //handle response depending on output element
        return function(resp) {
            if (resp.rows) {
                createTable(resp, element);
            } else {
                //no rows returned
                if (resp.error) {
                    var tableID = element;
                    clearTable(tableID);
                    var tableDiv = document.getElementById(tableParentDiv);
                    var tableElement = document.createElement('table');
                    tableElement.id = tableID;

                    if (resp.error.code) {
                        var errorText = "Error code: " + resp.error.code;
                        errorText += '\n' + resp.error.message;
                        tableElement.innerHTML = errorText;
                    } else {
                        tableElement.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred " + resp.error;
                    }
                    tableDiv.appendChild(tableElement);
                    if (resp.error.code == 401) {
                        checkAuth(); //debug only
                    }

                } else {
                    alert("No results for that search. Check spelling and select from options.");
                     clearTable(element);
                } 
            }
        };
    }
    if (lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('select') != 0 &&
        lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('show') != 0 &&
        lowerCaseQuery.indexOf('describe') != 0) {
        // is update query
        var body = 'sql=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
        runClientRequest({
            path: path,
            body: body,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Content-Length': body.length
            },
            method: 'POST'
        }, callback(element));
    } else {
        runClientRequest({
            path: path,
            params: { 'sql': query }
        }, callback(element));
    }
}

// Execute the client request.
function runClientRequest(request, callback) {
    var restRequest = gapi.client.request(request);
    console.log("the restRequest is: " + JSON.stringify(restRequest));
    restRequest.execute(callback);
}
```

Comment: Found the issue, it was unrelated to the OAuth process and a problem with the google apps domain permissions for the organization blocking access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity: The issue was not the OAuth process, it was a problem with the user not having the correct google apps domain permissions set. When the organization opened the fusion table service for the users subdomain, the error went away.